# Identify IC SOT26 1K

Tags: identification

I wonder what that could be: an SOT26 with 1K marking on it.

SOT23 with 1K should be a BC848B, but mine is an SOT26.

Do you have a clue?

[image]

The component resides inbetween the open collector FETs and the half bridge. (see picture)

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the actual IC.

Comment: Here you are... I have added a pic. It is bad quality but still recognizable I think.

Comment: And what about the surrounding components/traces... This could be a Richtek RT9801BCE low voltage detect IC. Commonly they sit close to some big IC without built-in LVD/BOD like a microcontroller. But I'm not making any sense of your schematic, so your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: RT9801BCE was also my first google hint but that is not the case. The surrounding ist shown in the schematic above. They sit inbetween the half bridge and the OC Mosfets..

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what type exactly but it is a bipolar pair like this:

[image]